# Find MAX value in column A for each Person when column B = X

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the MAX value in the "Value" column for each different "PersonID" column  only when the "AcuteCode" column is equal '1234'.  The first table in my image is what I'm trying to query and the second table are my desired results.

**Table example**

[image]

Comment: This is a very basic sql query using GROUP BY to aggregate and WHERE to filter: `SELECT personid, acutecode, max(value) from <table> WHERE acutecode = '1234' GROUP BY personid, acutecode;`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PersonID, AcuteCode, Max(Value) as Value
FROM yourTable
WHERE AcuteCode = 1234
GROUP BY PersonID, AcuteCode
```